# Use of unresolved identifier 'UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad'

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7

I've created a new Swift-based project using Xcode 7.2. Upon writing the following code within the viewDidLoad() method in my ViewController.swift file:

```
if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad {

}
```

I get the error message "Use of unresolved identifier 'UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad'", and the compiler won't proceed.

I suspected it was something to do with the "import UIKit" at the top? For some reason if I delete that line and begin typing "import UI" it doesn't provide me autocomplete options at all.

Things I've tried:

- Restarting computer and Xcode
- Deleting derived data folder
- Creating a new project in Swift
- Trying out the code in an Objective-C based project (works!)

Questions:

- Why am I getting this error message?
- Why doesn't "import UIKit" autocomplete?

Thanks!

Comment: Use UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad instead of UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Any idea on the reason why "import UIKit" doesn't autocomplete?

Comment: Not exactly know but i think If you go through the UIKit class for UIUserInterfaceIdiom, it's a enum type. so for  accessing enum values we have to write enum name and with (.) we can access their values.

Comment: Ok, thank you heaps! :)

Comment: If you want to write an answer I'll make sure to accept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use

**Swift 2**

```
if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad {

}
```

**Swift 3**

```
if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad {

}
```

instead of

```
if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad {

}
```

Hope it help you .. :)

Comment: According to a UIKit comment `The UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() function is provided for use when deploying to a version of the iOS less than 3.2. If the earliest version of iPhone/iOS that you will be deploying for is 3.2 or greater, you may use -[UIDevice userInterfaceIdiom] directly.`